# Jquery ui dialog widget add buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I wanted to add new button to the dialog, with out loosing the previous buttons.
I had used the following code which didn't work ....

```
 menu.dialog("open");
                var buttons = menu.dialog("option", "buttons");
                //$.extend(buttons, {text: label, click: function(){ alert("Added New Poker Face"); } });
                buttons[label] = function () { alert("Addded New poker Face"); };
                menu.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
```

I had even used extend to overwrite the buttons list, which is commented above no luck 
plz any work around for this

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) says the return value of `.dialog("option", "buttons")` can either be an object `{label1: click1, label2: click2, ...}` or an array `[{"text": label1, "click": click1}, {"text": label2, "click": click2}, ...]`.

Have you checked the format of `buttons` ? If it is an array, you should `.push()` your new button.

Comment: It returns object. I had used extend function, though its not working

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like below that worked for me.....

```
                //gets the list of buttons.
                var buttons = menu.dialog("option", "buttons");
                //Adds the new button to the existing list of buttons.
                buttons.push({ text: label, click: function () { alert("Addded New poker Face"); } });                
                //Gives the new list of buttons to the dialog to display.
                menu.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
```